# VS Code - How to setup the c_cpp_properties.json file for multiple Win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am looking for the correct way of setting up the paths in the mentioned `.json` file.
I am working with different PCs, using *Git* to merge both and "sadly" the paths to the *MinGW* libs are different.

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
            ]
        },
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4}
```

Is it now correct to add just the paths of both PCs so that one PC each is looking to the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the approach of setting an environment variable i.e. `MINGW_GCC_PATH` on each PC which can then be used via `${env:MINGW_GCC_PATH}` in your case:

```
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "${env:MINGW_GCC_PATH}"
        ]
    },
```

In my case instead of setting `"browse" {...},` I used:

```
    "compilerPath": "${env:MINGW_GCC_PATH}/bin/gcc.exe",
```

NOTE: As you are using gcc I would also recommend changing  `"intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"` to `"intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"`